# Why do we want that the determinant of the coefficients is $0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Eigenvalue problem with periodic boundary conditions-complete Fourier series

$$y''+\lambda y=0, 0 \leq x \leq L$$
$$(*): \begin{cases}
y(0)=y(L)\\[4pt]
y'(0)=y'(L)
\end{cases}$$
$$$$
It's a Sturm-Liouville problem.

$$y(x)=c \sin (\sqrt{\lambda }x)+d \cos( \sqrt{\lambda }x)$$
$$y'(x)=\sqrt{\lambda} c \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)-d \sqrt{\lambda} \sin( \sqrt{\lambda}x)$$

$(*):$$$y(0)=y(L) \Rightarrow d =c \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}L)+d \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}L)$$
$$y'(0)=y'(L) \Rightarrow c =c \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}L)-d \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}L)$$

Why do we want that the determinant of the coefficients is $0$?
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}L) & \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}L)-1\\ 
\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}L)-1  & -\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}L)
\end{bmatrix}=0$$

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I tried to find the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions in an other way...

Could you tell me if it's also correct??

At the case $\lambda >0: \\ $
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda} x)}+c_2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}$$
$$y(0)=y(L) \Rightarrow c_1=c_1 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}+c_2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)} \ (1)$$
$$y'(0)=y'(L) \Rightarrow c_2=-c_1 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}+c_2 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)} \ (2)$$
$$c_2(1)-c_1(2): 0=c_2^2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)}+c_1^2  \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)} \Rightarrow \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)} (c_1^2+c_2^2)=0 \Rightarrow \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}=0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{n \pi}{L}$$

Is this correct?? In my notes, with the first way, it is $$\sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{2 n \pi}{L}$$
Which of them is correct??

Comment: If the determinant is $0$, then there exist nontrivial coefficients $(c, d)$, which satisfy boundary conditions. If the determinant nonequal to $0$, then there exists only trivial solution $(c, d) = (0, 0)$ (in this case your solution $y(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, L]$, and it is not interesting).

Comment: @Voliar Thank you for your answer!!! :-)

Comment: I tried to find the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions in an other way.Could you tell me if it's also correct?? At the case $\lambda >0:$
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda} x)}+c_2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}$$
$$y(0)=y(L) \Rightarrow c_1=c_1 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}+c_2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)} \ (1)$$
$$y'(0)=y'(L) \Rightarrow c_2=-c_1 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}+c_2 \cos{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)} \ (2)$$
$$c_2(1)-c_1(2): 0=c_2^2 \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)}+c_1^2  \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda} L)} \Rightarrow \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)} (c_1^2+c_2^2)=0 \Rightarrow \sin{(\sqrt{\lambda}L)}=0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{n \pi}{L}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first way is correct. Assume that the second way is correct too. If we substitute 
$$
\sqrt{\lambda} = \frac{\pi}{L}
$$
to the boundary condition $y(0) = y(L)$, we get
$$
c_1 = -c_1.
$$
This is possible only for $c_1 =0$. However, in this case the second boundary condition will get us $c_2 = -c_2$, which imply $c_2 = 0$. Thus, we get $(c_1, c_2) = (0, 0)$, which is non-interesting case.

Comment: So is the second way completely wrong and we cannot apply it here? Or have I done something wrong at the calculations?

Comment: @MaryStar It is partially-correct, since some other roots appear. This happens since when you multiply by $c_1$ and $c_2$ you don't avoid the cases when some of this coefficients are zero. To make your approach absolutely correct, you just need to discard the extra roots (by checking that $\sqrt{\lambda} = \frac{(2k+1) \pi}{L}$ are not suitable).

Comment: I got stuck right now... Why are $$\sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{(2k+1) \pi}{L}$$ not suitable?

Comment: In my answer I checked the case $k=0$. The approach for other $k$ is absolutely similar.